# Collecting continuous rating data array from a slider or dial on a web page

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, slider

We need to create a web page with a control (a slider or dial), and we need to collect continuous data from users as they adjust that control over time.  For example, if the user stays on the page for 1 minute and they continuously adjust the level of the slider or dial up and down, we'd like to get the value of the slider or dial every 1 second (so we would end up with an array of 60 values in this case).
   In the past, we have collected a single value from the user using dxhtml slider and basic PHP form processing.  This works great.  However, this only gives a single value -- the value of the slider when they hit submit.
   Now we need to get an array of values.  We'd like to have this array passed to our PHP processing code when the user is done with the page, perhaps when they hit a done or submit button.  In this sense, our needs are not truly continuous/real time -- we only need to have the user input the data continuously and keep track of it somehow, we don't need to process it until the user is done with the page and hits done or submit.
   We'd like to do this in the 'lightest' way, using simple javascript/PHP if possible rather than complex analytics packages.
   Not sure if there are existing libraries for doing this sort of thing -- hope so.
   Thank you very much for your help.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you have a good idea what you want, but what have you tried? Do you have some code samples?

Comment: This is how we do it currently, obtaining a single value from a slider: <script>
var sld = new dhtmlxSlider("pain_before_slider", {size:400,skin: "arrowgreen",vertical:false,step:.1,min:-.1,max:10,value:-.1});
sld.linkTo("pain_before");
sld.init();
</script>